# JSF issue with changing default radioselection

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Im using the h:selectOneRadio  and having issues when I try to change the default radio selection. Below is the JSF code

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="radioSelectID1" layout="pageDirection" value="#{scheduleBean.selectedRecurrenceValue}"   immediate="true" >
                                        <f:selectItem id="dailyID" itemLabel="#{adminBean.adminScreenLabelVO.dailyLabel}" itemValue="#{scheduleBean.dailyValue}"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItem id="weeklyID" itemLabel="#{adminBean.adminScreenLabelVO.weeklyLabel}" itemValue="#{scheduleBean.weeklyValue}"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItem id="monthlyID" itemLabel="#{adminBean.adminScreenLabelVO.monthlyLabel}" itemValue="#{scheduleBean.monthlyValue}"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{scheduleBean.recurrenceChange}" render="recurrencePanelID" />
                                    </h:selectOneRadio>
```

below is the backingbean code for the selectedRecurrenceValue

```
public String getSelectedRecurrenceValue() {

    if(selectedRecurrenceValue == null)
    {
        selectedRecurrenceValue = adminScheduledetailsVO.getFrequency();
        if(selectedRecurrenceValue.equalsIgnoreCase(dailyValue))
        {
            dailyPanelRenderer = true ;
        }
        if(selectedRecurrenceValue.equalsIgnoreCase(weeklyValue))
        {
            dailyPanelRenderer = false ;
            weeklyPanelRenderer = true ;
        }

        if(selectedRecurrenceValue.equalsIgnoreCase(monthlyValue))
        {
            monthlyPanelRenderer = true ;
        }
    }

    return selectedRecurrenceValue;
}
```

The issue occurs when I try to change the radioselection option. Im unable to initialize the value selectedRecurrenceValue, since Im getting it dynamically.  When I try to select another radio button, Im receiving a null pointer exception for selectedRecurrenceValue. 
Any pointers to fix the issue would be really helpful.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where does the NPE happen? In the setter for selectedRecurrenceValue? Could you add the setter method to your question?

Comment: Hi Matt, I have added the setter method already and tried to debug the code as well when I try to select a new option. What happens is, on selecting the new option, the control directly comes to the getter method of selectedRecurrenceValue and the  NPE occur @ selectedRecurrenceValue = adminScheduledetailsVO.getFrequency();. adminScheduledetailsVO seems to be null. Looks like the new option that I have selected is not set. Not sure why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question right it seems that you don't need the field `selectedRecurrenceValue` and should bind `adminScheduledetailsVO.frequency` directly to your selectOneRadio:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="radioSelectID1" 
                  layout="pageDirection" 
                  value="#{scheduleBean.adminScheduledetailsVO.frequency}" >
```

Then of course `adminScheduledetailsVO` needs to be initialized before to avoid the NPE.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the response. But Im not sure, can you pls let me know what should I initialize it to.

Comment: You should create a new instance during or after construction of your bean.